# Copying a file to the startup folder Windows 10 VB.net

Tags: vb.net, file-copying

I'm trying to copy a program file to the windows 10 start up folder so when the user turns their computer on this program will also start up.

However every time i close the program the "Error" message pops up that i have told it to do if the try fails.

here is my code

```
Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
    Dim Location As String = "C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\BK94W342.09X\Y2ZQNR9E.C06\netw..tion_9d5f77662cbecf48_0001.0000_becfdf7c1bd783a8\Network Tester.exe"
    Dim Destination As String = "C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"

    Try
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(Destination)
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory(Location.Contains("Network Tester")) Then
            ''nothing
        ElseIf Not My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory(Location.Contains("Network Tester")) Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Location, Destination)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error")
    End Try

End Sub
```

thanks

Comment: right.... of course that "error" is what I have told it to do if it fails, do you have any idea why this wont work?

Comment: hint - Post the actual text of the exception. ;) easiest way - remove the try catch code and run it.

Comment: well when i close the app, it wont even show an error, it just shows the all mighty error and then nothing

Comment: Change the line that show the error to MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) and tell us what do you read.